# Should I use Secrets Manager for storing customers' API keys?

Tags: amazon-web-services, secret-key, aws-secrets-manager

I'm implementing a service that requires me to call my customers' API using their API keys. My customers will provide me with their API keys in their accounts.

When I'm calling my customers' API, I have to retrieve their API key before making the call. Since these are my customers' API keys and I want them to be kept safely, I'm considering keeping all of them in AWS Secrets Manager. I have roughly about 5,000 users (still growing) and I plan to store all their keys into a single secret in Secrets Manager. My application makes about a few millions calls to my customers API a month and it needs to retrieve the keys at high frequency and concurrency.

However, I'm not sure if this is the kind of use case for Secrets Manager because their docs sound to me like it was meant for just keeping secret information for the application and not for customers like a database. At the same time, storing encrypted keys in the database and having to decrypt them with a KMS key sounds like I may end up with roughly the same cost.

Is Secrets Manager meant for such a use case to store customers' sensitive information such as API keys? If not, what should I consider in my case?

Comment: This sounds more like a job for Hashicorp Vault, but I think you can use ASM for this without the extra hassle of running Vault in production, assuming you don't need the other benefits of Vault such as dynamic certs for tls and dynamic database creds, and fine-grained access control.

Comment: @SoftwareEngineer Is there a similar service within the AWS ecosystem?

Comment: Hashicorp Vault is the preeminent tool in its domain. There is nothing like it anywhere. Nothing else even comes close. If you are serious about secrets then you should use Vault. Everyone else is just playing games and waiting to be hacked. And no, I don't work for hashicorp or one of their partners :) But I have worked with Vault, and its best in class.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

50k api keys in a single secret is goinfg to be very unwieldy.  Assuming a 40 byte token, you're looking at 2mb of data - SSM has a max data length for a value of 4096 bytes unless I'm mistaken.

To me it would make more sense to generate a key with KMS and use that key to encrypt customer API keys before writing them to a DynamoDB table (or even RDS if you so desire)  When you need to use a customer API key, fetch it from dynamoDB, decrypt it with the KMS key, and then make use of it.

If you want automatic key rotation, SSM could be used to encrypt the key you use to encrypt the client API tokens.  Your token decryption key would remain usable while the wrapping SSM entry would be reencrypted with a key rotation set by policy.

Finally, as [Software Engineer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2051454/software-engineer) suggested above, there is Vault.

Comment: Sorry, I had a typo earlier with the number. I'm currently having at around 5k, not 50k yet. But I can imagine as it grows, it might reach a much higher number. So I can imagine what you're saying. You mentioned using SSM with key rotation, but if I had encrypted my API tokens with `Key A` and then later it got rotated to `Key B`, how would I still be able to decrypt the tokens since the key is now different?

Comment: @Carven SSM has versioning.  AWS will always return the most recent version, decrypted by its corresponding key, unless you request a prior version.  SSM transparently handles key rotation so you have to worry less about it.